# How to create a 'blog settings' tab in drupal to move all blog related edit forms to one place

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-6, tabs

I dont know if im asking the impossible, but i want to have a tab in my user edit area that houses all blog related items (ie blog theme, blog info, user blogroll) as opposed to them being inside the user/%/edit and user/%/edit profile.

Im putting together a multi-user site and this is crucial for user-friendliness.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is impossible with Drupal, but doing this would be a challenge.

With [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) you can alter any form you want. The code for this would have to go to a custom module. Then you would have to recreate the form, with a page callback, and handle the validation and submission. You can probably recreate the code from the modules that create the forms in the first place.

Alternative, you can just leave the settings at user/%/edit and other places, and just create a special form with all blog relevant info. That way the users choose where to edit their info. It will probably be a better choice, since the "blog settings" that's location at user/%/edit, will be more tied to the user, than to the blog. So when a user wants to edit some of his personal details, that's when he would want to edit those blog settings as well.

Your specific might be different, but the default setup is usually a very good default.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

I was able to write the correct function that imported the visual form into the new tab and take it out of the user tab...but the form was only visual and not functional. It would not save the information entered. I suppose this has to do withthe validation and submission. Any ideas?

Comment: @MAds: Update your question with the code for the form you created.